# A synonym for "software version which removed a feature"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, software

I'm looking for a synonym for software version where a usable feature was removed:

> The new version is a ______, the only improvements are cosmetic, I'm staying at 2.9.

The terms that come to mind are 'downdate' and 'downgrade', but they also mean a return to previous version, regardless of the quality or feature set of current version.

I'm positive there is more specific term which I'm unable to recall.

Comment: I think _downgrade_ is correct and that he other term for a _downdate_ is a _regression_. If you think about physical consumer goods a new model is often inferior to the original for economic reasons. A car maker could launch a  new model (lets call it a 'Midas') with leather seats; state of the art sound system; sport, comfort and economy performance modes and so on but find that it was too expensive. They could then introduce a new Midas, still called the same and looking similar but much less luxurious. The new Midas would not be a return to a previous model but would be a downgrade.

Comment: Are you asking what it *should* be called, or what it *will* be called??

Comment: @BoldBen Thanks, 'regression' is actually closer IMO. I like this car example.

Comment: @HotLicks Likely *could*. I'm looking for proper term for this phenomenon, with no unnecessary emotional colouring.

Comment: If you're not looking for emotional colouring, you need to edit your question to remove the words **useless**, **useful**, and **quality**. As it is, they are pushing answers toward something normative. You are also confusing the issue by mentioning on the one hand something being added and on the other hand something being removed . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford I described a common situation when new software version isn't well-received by user base because of its feature set. I edited the question for clarity. Regarding emotional colouring, I'm not looking for pejorative terms such as 'junkware', unless they specifically describe this situation.

Comment: If it's only a cosmetic change, the industry might call it a **minor update** or a **point release**. The aspect of "removing a feature" is not one that applies to the name of the newer version specifically. The lack of the feature itself is indeed a "regression" (or if somebody actually prefers it the old way it could be thought of as "classic" or "retro"), but that name won't be applied to the release.

Comment: A backward step -example usage at https://ion.icaew.com/itcounts/b/weblog/posts/softwareupdatessometimesabackwardstep

Comment: @JasonBassford That's why I initially referred to added and removed features. Sometimes a release is marketed as major, while it offers several insignificant improvements and important features are removed (usually because of poor project management). Good point about feature vs release regression, thanks.

Comment: @k1eran Thank you, consider providing it as an answer if you will. 'Retrograde step' was mentioned there and sounds like proper term, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*a backward step* or *a step backwards*

Examples in this article at https://ion.icaew.com/itcounts/b/weblog/posts/softwareupdatessometimesabackwardstep

> Software updates – sometimes a **backward** step?
>   [...]
>   In the meantime….what “upgrades” have you had that have appeared more as a **retrograde** step?

Comment: Thanks, my upvote will take effect once I have enough privileges here.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about feature removal specifically in software:

- cleanup (We have cleaned up some of the unused features)
- obsolete (Removed obsolete features)
- downgrade (This version downgrades dependent code due to bugs)
- retraction (We retracted new UI, it was too buggy)